# avoid function returned object null check

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Is there any way to avoid null check on function returned object in java like @NonNull annotation used in the Lombok project which can be used on the parameter of methods or constructors.

Is there any better practice to do this check...

```
    User user = service.findOne(id);
    if (user != null)
        return user;
    throw new UserNotFoundException("Invalid ID - "+ id);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some methods you can use that do this:

```
x.getClass();
```

A cheesy one, used in the JDK itself a lot. The problem is, if `x` is null, then this produces a `NullPointerException` without any message. The advantage is, starting with some future java version (probably java 15), the error message WILL include information about what was null (so, 'x' will appear in the message of the exception). Sometimes the simplest thing is the best.

But, if that doesn't suit:

```
java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(x, "x");
```

will also do it. That method even returns 'x' so you can use it in a passthrough fashion if you like. This will throw an NPE with message `x` if x is null.

guava has a similar method, but I'd stick with the one that's in the JDK itself.

Note that you can configure lombok to generate its nullcheck with `Objects.requireNonNull` if you prefer this, by adding a line to your  `lombok.config`.